# Why does pd.rolling and .apply() return multiple outputs from a function returning a single value?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I'm trying to create a rolling function that:

1. Divides two DataFrames with 3 columns in each df.
2. Calculate the mean of each row from the output in step 1.
3. Sums the averages from step 2.

This could be done by using pd.iterrows() hence looping through each row. However, this would be inefficient when working with larger datasets. Therefore, my objective is to create a pd.rolling function that could do this much faster.

What I would need help with is to understand why my approach below returns multiple values while the function I'm using only returns a single value.

*EDIT* : I have updated the question with the code that produces my desired output.

This is the test dataset I'm working with:

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

#create two dataframes
values = {'column1': [7,2,3,1,3,2,5,3,2,4,6,8,1,3,7,3,7,2,6,3,8],
        'column2': [1,5,2,4,1,5,5,3,1,5,3,5,8,1,6,4,2,3,9,1,4],
        "column3" : [3,6,3,9,7,1,2,3,7,5,4,1,4,2,9,6,5,1,4,1,3]
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(values)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4],[3,4,1],[3,6,1]])
print(df1)
print(df2)

    column1  column2  column3
0         7        1        3
1         2        5        6
2         3        2        3
3         1        4        9
4         3        1        7
5         2        5        1
6         5        5        2
7         3        3        3
8         2        1        7
9         4        5        5
10        6        3        4
11        8        5        1
12        1        8        4
13        3        1        2
14        7        6        9
15        3        4        6
16        7        2        5
17        2        3        1
18        6        9        4
19        3        1        1
20        8        4        3
   0  1  2
0  2  3  4
1  3  4  1
2  3  6  1
```

One method to achieve my desired output by looping through each row:

```
RunningSum = []
for index, rows in df1.iterrows():
    if index > 3:
        Div = abs((((df2 / df1.iloc[index-3+1:index+1].reset_index(drop="True").values)-1)*100))
        Average = Div.mean(axis=0)
        SumOfAverages = np.sum(Average)
        RunningSum.append(SumOfAverages)
        
        
            
        #printing my desired output values
        print(RunningSum)
[330.42328042328046,
 212.0899470899471,
 152.06349206349208,
 205.55555555555554,
 311.9047619047619,
 209.1269841269841,
 197.61904761904765,
 116.94444444444444,
 149.72222222222223,
 430.0,
 219.51058201058203,
 215.34391534391537,
 199.15343915343914,
 159.6031746031746,
 127.6984126984127,
 326.85185185185185,
 204.16666666666669]
```

However, this would be timely when working with large datasets. Therefore, I've tried to create a function which applies to a pd.rolling() object.

```
def SumOfAverageFunction(vals):
    Div = df2 / vals.reset_index(drop="True")
    Average = Div.mean(axis=0)
    SumOfAverages = np.sum(Average)
    return SumOfAverages

RunningSum = df1.rolling(window=3,axis=0).apply(SumOfAverageFunction)
```

The problem here is that my function returns multiple output. How can I solve this?

```
print(RunningSum)
     column1   column2   column3
0        NaN       NaN       NaN
1        NaN       NaN       NaN
2   3.214286  4.533333  2.277778
3   4.777778  3.200000  2.111111
4   5.888889  4.416667  1.656085
5   5.111111  5.400000  2.915344
6   3.455556  3.933333  5.714286
7   2.866667  2.066667  5.500000
8   2.977778  3.977778  3.063492
9   3.555556  5.622222  1.907937
10  2.750000  4.200000  1.747619
11  1.638889  2.377778  3.616667
12  2.986111  2.005556  5.500000
13  5.333333  3.075000  4.750000
14  4.396825  5.000000  3.055556
15  2.174603  3.888889  2.148148
16  2.111111  2.527778  1.418519
17  2.507937  3.500000  3.311111
18  2.880952  3.000000  5.366667
19  2.722222  3.370370  5.750000
20  2.138889  5.129630  5.666667
```

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @sygneto! I want to achieve the same output as when I'm using .iterrows() method, but with pd.rolling() instead

Comment: So for each row in df1, I want to divide the last three rows with the values in df2. Then sum the averages of each "divided" row

Comment: @sygneto Do you think its possible?

Answer (score 0):

After reordering of operations, your calculations can be simplified

```
BASE = df2.sum(axis=0) /3
BASE_series = pd.Series({k: v for k, v in zip(df1.columns, BASE)})
result = df1.rdiv(BASE_series, axis=1).sum(axis=1)

print(np.around(result[4:], 3))
```

Outputs:

```
4     5.508
5     4.200
6     2.400
7     3.000
...
```

if you dont want to calculate anything before index 4 then change:

```
df1.iloc[4:].rdiv(...
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a great solution. However, my bad, I have updated the question. I'm trying to divide column wise for every row. Is it possible to use your soulution for this as well?